# How to display alert message in view page using viewbag

Tags: javascript, alert

In Cshtml the following doesn't work

```
ViewBag.alert = @"<script language='javascript'>alert('Plan Already Exists');</script>";
```

How can i achieve this

Answer (score 4):

I am using MVC Razor with C#, and I got this logic to work in my view by updating it a bit:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("@ViewBag.Message");
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `ViewBag.alert` as string to `alert()` function. Currently you are assign string to `ViewBag.alert`

*Use*

```
<script>
    alert('@ViewBag.alert');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a message to the ViewBag in your controller.

```
 public ActionResult Index() {
            ViewBag.Message = "Plan Already Exists";
            return View();
        }
```

And then in your view, add a bit of script:

```
 <% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message)) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('<%=ViewBag.Message%>');
    </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Doesnt Seem to work. the code after the alert code is a redirect code. Is this y it doesnt work . I want the user to click ok on the script thenn i want him to see a new page . the redirect park is working but no alerts are shown.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Like this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.msg = "View Bag Value";

    return View();
}
```

View:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.msg))
{
     <script type="text/javascript">alert('@ViewBag.msg');</script>
}
```